# Android Custom Launcher Start Multiple Times

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, boot, launcher

I created a simple launcher.
I started from empty activity, after I only edited MainActivity and Manifest.
The problem is that when device boot, my launcher start, but seems that app start, it is closed after 4 seconds and another instance start.
I need that at boot, launcher start only once.

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v("TEST", "1");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mylauncher">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving launch mode singleTask

```
<activity   android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            >
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed. This is a problem because if i want to insert a video into videoview as splash screen, video start, but after 4 seconds another app instance seems to start.